# NameError: name 'TabularList' is not defined

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.tabular import *
from fastai.tabular.all import *
import pandas as pd

# set seed for reproducibility
custom_set_seed(42)

df = pd.read_csv('credit_card_default.csv', index_col=0, na_values='')
df.head()

DEP_VAR = 'default_payment_next_month'

num_features = list(df.select_dtypes('number').columns)
num_features.remove(DEP_VAR)
cat_features = list(df.select_dtypes('object').columns)

preprocessing = [FillMissing, Categorify, Normalize]

data = (TabularList.from_df(df, cat_names=cat_features, cont_names=num_features, procs=preprocessing).split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42).label_from_df(cols=DEP_VAR).databunch())
```

I have been trying to run this piece of code but it keeps running into this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-5ca7e57a8e36> in <module>
      1 # Create a TabularDataBunch from the DataFrame
      2 
----> 3 data = (TabularList.from_df(df, cat_names=cat_features, cont_names=num_features, procs=preprocessing).split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42).label_from_df(cols=DEP_VAR).databunch())

NameError: name 'TabularList' is not defined
```

I believe I have imported all the modules that were needed. Can someone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check with the full path import  as below

```
from fastai.tabular.data import TabularList
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Pankaj78691 but it does not seem to work. I'm getting an import error now:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0192f885a30a> in <module>
      2 from fastai.tabular import *
      3 from fastai.tabular.all import *
----> 4 from fastai.tabular.data import TabularList
      5 
      6 import pandas as pd

ImportError: cannot import name 'TabularList' from 'fastai.tabular.data' (c:\users\khuba\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\fastai\tabular\data.py)

Comment: @KhubaibAbdullah  then you may want to check if fastai is In the path or you could start python interactive shell and try to import and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by installing an older fastai i.e.

```
 pip install fastai==1.0.61
```

then

```
from fastai.tabular.data import TabularList
```

works with no problems.